# How to correctly set the time given when using date('Y-m-d') in php?

Tags: php, datetime, server

When I set the timezone to my current location (eg: Nairobi GMT +3)
And then ask for the time using date('Y-m-d'), I get an incorrect value for minutes. i.e if it`s 11:03 AM it shows 11:15 AM (so +12 minutes difference).

Below is the code used. Pretty basic. Gets the job done.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Nairobi"); 
//echo date_default_timezone_get(); 
echo date('H:i:s');
```

Also this time difference only occurs in my client`s server. In other test servers , it provides accurate time. i.e 11:03 AM will show 11:03 AM.

Am I required to change the timezone in php.ini as well?

**EDIT:**

1. The project isn`t in localhost.
2. The output of time before & after the timezone set is the same :/

Comment: is your project in local server

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP. It's the time on the server that differs. Sync both servers against ntp.

Comment: If the time is the same before and after the timezone is set, it just means that the server already is set to that timezone.

Comment: @Magnus Thanks. I had come to the same conclusion as well. What I need is to know If I need to work on the php.ini file or is there another php script to solve this.

Comment: You already have the solution! Sync the servers time with NTP - **It has nothing to do with PHP** @Blazeag even gave you the correct command to do it, if you are on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your system time is 12 minutes ahead. If you are under linux, try

```
ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
```

Comment: Don't forget `sudo` :)

Comment: Yeah, sudo or as root, thank you @Magnus Eriksson ;)

Answer (score 2):

Likely the server system time is ahead 12 minutes

Answer (score 0):

what's the output of date before you set the timezone?

What's the ouput of

```
print_r(get_defined_vars())
```

Comment: The output of the above is a (very) long list of information which provides nothing relevant to the issue faced.